# Depression or depth effect in Flutter

Tags: flutter

While checking the Card Widget, I found out that it takes only positive elevation. Is there a specific widget that we can use to create a depression effect with some depth just like shown in the image attached?

[image: depression_effect]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you are looking for is neumorphic effect, [flutter_neumorphic](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_neumorphic)

```
Neumorphic(
  style: NeumorphicStyle(
    shape: NeumorphicShape.concave,
    boxShape: NeumorphicBoxShape.roundRect(BorderRadius.circular(12)), 
    depth: -5,
    lightSource: LightSource.topLeft,
    color: Colors.grey
  ),
  child: ...
)
```